# Fill separate colors for different Bezier Paths

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I am trying to add separate colors to different bezierPaths like this

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_v_sticker.frame.size);

UIColor *fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
[fillColor setFill];
UIColor *strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[strokeColor setStroke];

p = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[p moveToPoint:CGPointMake(60, 10)];
[p addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(110, 60)];
[p addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(60, 110)];
[p addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(10, 60)];
[p closePath];
[p fill];
[p stroke];

fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
[fillColor setFill];
strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[strokeColor setStroke];

p2 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[p2 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 10)];
[p2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(150, 60)];
[p2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 110)];
[p2 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(50, 60)];
[p2 closePath];
[p2 fill];
[p2 stroke];

CGMutablePathRef combinedPath = CGPathCreateMutableCopy(p.CGPath);
CGPathAddPath(combinedPath, NULL, p2.CGPath);
combined = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:combinedPath];
CFRelease(combinedPath);

mask = [CAShapeLayer new];
mask.path = combined.CGPath;

[_v_sticker.layer addSublayer:mask];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But I am getting nothing except color black. I can give color to the layer But i want to assign different colors directly and use them in a single layered bezier path

Can anyone tell me where am i doing mistake?

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in your code:

1. You create an image context but you don't access the image (`UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`).
2. You set no colors (e.g. `backgroundColor`, `strokeColor`) in your mask layer.

Comment: i am using the layer property to show the bezier content instead of rendering image form it because the rendered image gets pixelated but the layer created over it don't. I need to specify the view background color but i want to give color to path directly and keep it as layer

Comment: I meant the mask layer. You have to set its colors as well.

Comment: ok but if set the mask layer color, it would cover every path added to layer, but i want to give different colors to different paths and then generate layer for it, so that it has color and quality

Comment: A `CAShapeLayer` can only draw a path with only on background, fill, and stroke color respectively. For drawing paths with different colors, you need several layers.